# How to start a child dialog from a different page other than it's first in CRM

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

So I have a link from a dialog to a child dialog in CRM. What I want to know, is if it is possible to start the child dialog from it's second page rather than its first, depending on some user input from the parent dialog. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Dialogs only offer very basic functionality. An alternative would be to develop a custom dialog based on an HTML webresource.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the response